# Inserting arrays in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I got a small problem regarding inserting my data into my database. I'll try to explain the data as precise as possible.

Im making a form maker, I already had a (bad practice) implementation, so Im rewriting it to a better implementation.

Tables:

```
app_forms
- id
- name

app_questions
- id
- form_id
- type
- name 
- label
- placeholder
- order

app_possible_answers
- id
- vraag_id
- label
- value
- order
```

These are my tables for creating my form. I think it speaks for itself how it works. I first create the form in the app_form, and there are questions (app_questions) which are linked to the form, and the app_possible_answers are for the select, radio and checkboxes type of question.

Below is a snippet of the textfield element if its get chosen to get added to the form:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span style="width:15%" style="width:15%" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="textfieldname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Field tablename" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required />
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="questionfornametextfield">?</span>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span style="width:15%" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Label</span>
    <input name="textfieldlabel[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Label" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required />
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="questionforlabeltextfield">?</span>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span style="width:15%" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">Placeholder</span>
    <input name="textfieldplaceholder[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" required />
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="questionforplaceholdertextfield">?</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, I give the inputs the name with [] behind it so it gets put in an array and sent to the server. This way I can make sure that multiple textfields are differentiated from eachother, and that I can add multiple textfields to my form.

Where I'm stuck at the moment is how I need to insert it into my database, like how can I group the data in the array together so the insert goes right.

This is the object that gets sent. This is a form with 2 textfields, I stringified it with JSON so that its more readable:

```
[
  {
    "name": "formname",
    "value": "Formname"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldtype[]",
    "value": "textfield"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldname[]",
    "value": "name textfield one"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldlabel[]",
    "value": "label textfield one"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldplaceholder[]",
    "value": "placeholder textfield one"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldtype[]",
    "value": "textfield"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldname[]",
    "value": "name textfield two"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldlabel[]",
    "value": "label textfield two"
  },
  {
    "name": "textfieldplaceholder[]",
    "value": "placeholder textfield two"
  }
]
```

But how do I make sure that the right data gets grouped and inserted in the app_questions table. I have this code of snippet in PHP but I'm stuck:

```
//formname
foreach($formelementen as $key => $value)
{
    //get form name
    if($key == 'formname')
    {
        echo $value . "\n";
    }   


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. I changed every field to the same name, so for every kind of type (is it textarea, textfield, etc.) so its type[], name[],

THan I use a for loop to count the arrays and check.